# Поиск preg_match_all

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Использую поиск по регулярным выражениям.

```
echo $balans = "Минус:35286,83р";
//echo $balans = "Баланс 114.80 р. Последний шанс выиграть 1 млн руб.! 1 день бесплатно!  Подкл.: *485#";
//echo $balans = "12.96р.*Что ждет вас в 2015 году? Узнайте у АСТРОЛОГа! *523*6# (3р/сут)";
//echo $balans = "OCTATOK 64.47 p. Запретите звонки и SMS от назойливых абонентов. Инф: 678";

preg_match_all("/[0-9]+(.|,)[0-9]+/",
    $balans,
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
echo $out[0][0] . "\n";
```

Но нужно выловить все, что до (35286,83; 114.80;  12.96; 64.47).

Так и не понял, как сделать маской, поэтому сделал костылем:

```
$outotv = preg_match_all("/[0-9]+(.|,)[0-9]+/", $balans, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER); //  маской ищем баланс
    if ($outotv > 0 ){
        $stpos = strpos($balans, $out[0][0]); // находим совпадении по маске
        $stpos = substr($balans, 0, $stpos); // режем до совпадения по маске
        $balans= $stpos . $out[0][0] . "р"; // тулим отрезанное к найденному в маске
}else{
    $balans= "нет данных";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
/(.*?)\d+[.,]\d+/
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. все работает
даже так все работает:
"/(.*?)[.,]\d+/"